# How can I switch from WiFi to mobile data without interrupting my current download in Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android, downloading, android-10

I am currently downloading a roughly 50 GB file in Chrome for Android (10). I am on my home WiFi. Given the speed of my network it should take roughly 8 hours. It is a regular file download which is being handled in the default way, just like when you download any file in Chrome.

I will have to take the device out of my house (thus outside of the WiFi range) later, and I do not wish to interrupt the download.

I have 1000 GB mobile data plan so I could just continue the download over 4G/LTE as I go out. But, as my internet connection switches to mobile data, will that interrupt the download, forcing me to start over again?

If so would it help to pause the download? I could then either resume it when I get back home (on the same WiFi network) or even if it would work to resume it once I am on mobile data?

Comment: You could do a little experiment, try downloading ths same 50 gb file for 1 or 2 mins on wifi. Then stop, give it a couple of seconds and then switch to mobile data. See if it starts downloading. If it continues, then you're fine, if not, try pausing on wifi. Disconnect from wifi for a minute. And then reconnect again, see if it continues. If it does then good day mate, if it doesn't, well may have to look for some alternatives (:

Comment: @honeymoly Well I am already halfway through the download, so if I were to try this experiment it would have to be on another device!

Comment: Well, if you happen to have one, better test it before going out.

Comment: @honeymoly Yeah good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you switch from Wifi to cell phone network your public IP changes and therefore seemless handover without interrupting a download is not yet possible.

There is a standard that is designed to allow such a seamless handover between e.g. Wifi and cell phone, it is called "Mobile IP". Effectively it works a bit like a VPN. No matter what internet connection you use your public IP remains the same and changing between Wifi and cell phone network is covered by the Mobile IP system.

Unfortunately at the moment such Mobile IP providers are not yet well established.

Besides that even with the current situation a number of web servers should allow to handle download interruptions: Well configured web servers allow to resume downloads, hence if the download stops (because of a network switch) and you continue it, it skips the bytes already downloaded and continues where you stopped. Of course this also has to be supported by the downloading app.

Comment: I'm curious if he got a VPN setup with the VPN then changes IP when he goes from cellular to Wi-Fi? Or would that be a workaround?

Comment: @TechBoyKev If the VPN would be UDP based and accepts the IP change of the VPN client without reconnect this could work.